# POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/unlock 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: laravel

I want to pass the unlock key to route using ajax but I am not allowed to do so. The code gives me method not allowed error.

I cant see the error in my code, whether it the route error or some other error

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.result-container').hide();
$('.unlock-btn').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{route('unlock')}}",
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            theme_id : {{$theme_id}},
            key : $('.key').val(),
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log('success');
            if(data === '0')
                $('.result-container').show();
            else
            {
                window.location = "{{route('view', ['theme_id' => $theme_id])}}";
            }
        }
    })
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: show the route in your web.php. May be it's a get route.

Comment: That's a method not allowed. I will make a wild guess that your endpoint you are trying to access is not a post.

Comment: Can you show your web.php file, the error implies that you are using method (POST) in the ajax request whereas they could be a different method in your web route.

Comment: Route::get('/unlock', 'ThemeController@unlock')->name('unlock');

Comment: Yeah I got it.. It was a mistake by me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your route is a get but in ajax you are sending post request. Change it to post.

```
Route::post('/unlock', 'ThemeController@unlock')->name('unlock');
```

And also add a token in data otherwise you will get 419 error for missing CSRF.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{route('unlock')}}",
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            theme_id : {{$theme_id}},
            key : $('.key').val(),
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log('success');
            if(data === '0')
                $('.result-container').show();
            else
            {
                window.location = "{{route('view', ['theme_id' => $theme_id])}}";
            }
        }
    })
```